# How do I prevent web forms for marketers from injecting its own jquery-ui.custom.Default.css

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I've been using [Web Forms for Marketers (WFFM)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,3.aspx) in a [Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/) project recently and I noticed that it injected:

```
<link href="/sitecore%20modules/shell/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/themes/colors//jquery-ui.custom.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Is there a way to disable the link so that only CSS files that I've specified are added to the page?

---

After reviewing more of the WFFM source, I've noticed that the unwanted `<link />` is added to the page via `Page.Header.Controls`:

```
if (page.Header != null)
{
    if (!flag)
    {
        try
        {
            //possibly added as link, unless an exception is thrown
            page.Header.Controls.Add((Control) htmlLink);
            linkDictionary.Add(key, key);
            continue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //added manually
            HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter((TextWriter) new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()));
            htmlLink.RenderControl(writer);
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof (Page), writer.InnerWriter.ToString(), writer.InnerWriter.ToString());
            flag = true;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Which means I could check all the header controls and hide the one that contains `"jquery-ui.custom.Default.css"`, but this still feels like a dirty-nasty-hack (which it is). It also wont remove the link in situations where `page.Header.Controls.Add` would throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Forms for Marketers will, in fact, *not* add the `<link>` tag if the stylesheet is not present in the filesystem.

The underlying issue turned out to be that [TDS](http://www.hhogdev.com/Products/Team-Development-for-Sitecore/Overview.aspx) had cached a copy of the removed stylesheet, and was adding it to the web directory on every build. Cleaning the build and making sure to clear the cached TDS files fixed the issue without needing to add server side code.

Answer (score 3):

I've de-compiled WFFM and it doesn't appear to be configurable to change it or turn it off. So, one way to get around this issue is to edit this file directly and wipe out its contents. It will still be loaded but won't include any CSS.

**UPDATE**

Per your updates, you could also try something like this:

```
Control ctl = WebUtil.FindControlOfType(Sitecore.Context.Page.Page, typeof(TYPE-OF-EXPECTED-CONTROL));
```

Where you replace `TYPE-OF-EXPECTED-CONTROL`. From here you can do whatever you want with it, e.g. figure out if its the link to include the CSS, etc.

Comment: I've already done that, but it's good advice anyway. I've been using dotPeek to check out the source, and I've found a check in `ThemesManager.AddScript` that looks like it should only be added if the file exists. Unfortunately, deleting the file doesn't seem to fix it. Re-compiling seems to bring the file back as well, I'm not sure why at the moment, it may have something to do with TDS.